# How to use array positional $ with aggregation projection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I had an aggregate call that was working when `revisions` was an Object (with the keys being the entryId).

```
await Project.aggregate([
  { $limit: 1 },
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId(projectId) } },
  {
    $project: {
      limits: 1,
      revisions: { $slice: [`$revisions.${entryId}.${languageId}`, startIndex, PageSize] },
      totalRevisions: {
        $size: { $ifNull: [`$revisions.${entryId}.${languageId}`, []] },
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

Now that I converted `revisions` to an array with entryId inside it, I'm not sure how to get the same result. I tried:

```
await Project.aggregate([
  { $limit: 1 },
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId(projectId),
      'revisions.entryId': ObjectId(entryId),
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      limits: 1,
      revisions: { $slice: [`$revisions.$.${languageId}`, startIndex, PageSize] },
      totalRevisions: {
        $size: { $ifNull: [`$revisions.$.${languageId}`, []] },
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

But I get the error:

> MongoError: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.

How can I use `$slice` and `$ifNull` with an item in an array? Thanks

Sample doc:

```
{
  "revisions" : [ 
    {
      "entryId" : ObjectId("5bbf8813c272e05171463bc4"),
      "5bbe76c6d3fb1a4f143f8304" : [ 
        {
          "authorId" : ObjectId("5b1c5384d75d9f3b0eb65c2a"),
          "revisionId" : ObjectId("5bbf8813c272e05171463bc7"),
          "updated" : "2018-10-11T17:27:47.842Z",
          "value" : "County"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: First could  not able to get why `$match` has been used if applied `$limit` first!!! And please post the sample document and output as well

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I was imagining that match would continue searching all documents even after the first match without it? Thanks, sample added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of the pipeline stages really matters here. When you use [**`$limit`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) before the [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) then it filters the data from the single document found in the [**`$limit`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) stage.

And if you will use [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) before the [**`$limit`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) then it will filter the documents from your all the collection inside the database and will throw single document in the [**`$limit`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) stage.

After that You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "_id": ObjectId(projectId),
    "revisions.entryId": ObjectId(entryId)
  }},
  {
    "$project": {
      "revisions": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$revisions",
          "in": {
            "$arrayToObject": {
              "$map": {
                "input": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$this" },
                    "as": "ee",
                    "cond": { "$eq": ["$$ee.k", "5bbe76c6d3fb1a4f143f8304"] }
                  }
                },
                "as": "dd",
                "in": {
                  "k": "$$dd.k",
                  "v": { "$slice": [startIndex, 1 ] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "totalRevisions": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$revisions",
              "in": {
                "$size": {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": {
                      "$filter": {
                        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$this" },
                        "as": "ee",
                        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$ee.k", "5bbe76c6d3fb1a4f143f8304"] }
                      }
                    },
                    "as": "dd",
                    "in": {
                      "k": "$$dd.k",
                      "v": { "$slice": [startIndex, 1] }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But If you are just started with your project then I will highly recommend you to don't go with this structure because your nested array keys are dynamic and playing with the dynamic keys are always like playing with naked electric wire.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, wow that's a complex looking aggregation! It is a new project so would you advise having languages in an array instead? Would rather get rid of the complexity as much as poss. In my head I think object lookups are computationally faster but it seems mongo is more comfortable with arrays (though in this case it seems not!).

Comment: Mongo is comfortable with the arrays but it is hard to apply operations on arrays and nested arrays and especially when the keys of an array are not static. So in my opinion you should make another collection for `entryId` and then can go for it. Refer [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation before start with your project.